# Unable to obtain data object from xml file with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong with this.  It worked for me on another page but it doesn't work for this page (capitalbikeshare).  The 'data' variable does contain an object but when I try to print out the length or a specific item it gives me an error msg saying that it cannot read property of null 'feed'.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml'),
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        var entry = data.responseData.feed.entries;
        var entry_length = entry.length;
        alert("success"+entry_length);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Here is a small sample of the XML file.

```
 <stations lastUpdate="1447107709602" version="2.0">
 <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
 <station>
 <id>1</id>
 <name>20th & Bell St</name>
 <terminalName>31000</terminalName>
 <lastCommWithServer>1447107692939</lastCommWithServer>
 <lat>38.8561</lat>
 <long>-77.0512</long>
 <installed>true</installed>
 <locked>false</locked>
 <installDate>0</installDate>
 <removalDate/>
 <temporary>false</temporary>
 <public>true</public>
 <nbBikes>5</nbBikes>
 <nbEmptyDocks>5</nbEmptyDocks>
 <latestUpdateTime>1447106879008</latestUpdateTime>
 </station>
 </stations>
```

Comment: What is in the `data` object?

Comment: Your ajax request seems to be to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml and the response is `{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "bad or missing callback or context", "responseStatus": 400}`

Comment: @TbWill4321  I updated my question with a small sample of the xml file.

Comment: @foxdonut Thats what's is frustrating me.  It worked for another page I tried it on but not for this one =(  is there any other way to get the data using ajax?

Comment: if you fix the callback parameter, you get - `{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Feed could not be loaded.", "responseStatus": 400}`

Answer (score 1):

That web service is intended to parse rss feeds not arbitrary XML.

Proper AJAX call

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    data: {
        v: "1.0",
        num: 10,
        q: 'https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(textStatus);
    }
});
```

responds with

```js
{
    "responseData": null,
    "responseDetails": "Feed could not be loaded.",
    "responseStatus": 400
}
```

by trying `data.responseData.feed.entries` you obviously can't access `feed` if `responseData` is `null`.

If you use a different web service like [cors.io](http://cors.io/) you can, instead of loading JSON, load xml and then access fields with jQuery.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://cors.io',
    dataType : 'xml',
    data: {
        u: 'https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $(data).find(">stations>station>name").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the JSON.stringify() api to dump out the content of your fetched data from AJAX to see if that property indeed exists.

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log('Dumping data object -> ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
}
```

If you are using chrome you can access the console output panel via "<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>".